# Aggregating a One-Hot Encoded feature in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am experienced in python but totally new to pyspark. I have dataframe that contains about 50M rows, with several categorical features. For each feature, I have One-Hot Encoded them. Here's a simplified but representative example of the code.

from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

```
df = sc.parallelize([
     (1, 'grocery'),
     (1, 'drinks'),
     (1, 'bakery'),
     (2, 'grocery'),
     (3, 'bakery'),
     (3, 'bakery'),
 ]).toDF(["id", "category"])

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='category', outputCol='categoryIndex')
encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol='categoryIndex', outputCol='categoryVec')

pipe = Pipeline(stages = [indexer, encoder])

newDF = pipe.fit(df).transform(df)
```

Giving output

```
+---+--------+-------------+-------------+
| id|category|categoryIndex|  categoryVec|
+---+--------+-------------+-------------+
|  1| grocery|          1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
|  1|  drinks|          2.0|    (2,[],[])|
|  1|  bakery|          0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|  2| grocery|          1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
|  3|  bakery|          0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|  3|  bakery|          0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
+---+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

I would now like to groupBy 'id' and aggregate the 'categoryVec' column with a sum, so I can get one row per id, with a vector that indicates which of the (possibly several) categories that customer was shopping in. In pandas this would be simply a case of applying sum/mean to each column produced in the `pd.get_dummies()` step, but here it doesn't seem to be so simple.

I will then pass the output to ML algorithms so I will need to be able to use VectorAssembler or similar on the output.

Oh, and I really need a pyspark solution.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Sample input please

Comment: @Suresh I hope I've added some useful code in the edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Counvectorizer for this. It converts category index array to encoded vector.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df = sc.parallelize([
     (1, 'grocery'),
     (1, 'drinks'),
     (1, 'bakery'),
     (2, 'grocery'),
     (3, 'bakery'),
     (3, 'bakery'),
 ]).toDF(["id", "category"]) \
   .groupBy('id') \
   .agg(F.collect_list('category').alias('categoryIndexes'))

cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol='categoryIndexes', outputCol='categoryVec')

transformed_df = cv.fit(df).transform(df)
transformed_df.show()
```

results:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|     categoryIndexes|         categoryVec|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|[grocery, drinks,...|(3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1...|
|  3|    [bakery, bakery]|       (3,[0],[2.0])|
|  2|           [grocery]|       (3,[1],[1.0])|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Very cool, thank you!
I assume I need to create a new CountVectorizer for each categorical feature? I have done it like that and it works, but there's no shortcut, is there?

Comment: You can use feature assembler for concatenating different features. But you should check that there is no the same categorical feature value in different categorie.