# Creating One-Hot Encoder. CountVectorizer returns error with ArrayType(IntergerType, true)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, one-hot-encoding

I try to create a one hot encoder for the following input data :

```
+------+--------------------+
|userid|     categoryIndexes|
+------+--------------------+
| 24868|              [7276]|
| 35335|             [12825]|
| 42634| .    [14550, 14550]|
| 51183|              [7570]|
| 61065|             [14782]|
| 70292|              [7282]|
| 72326|      [14883, 14877]|
| 96632|             [14902]|
| 99703|             [14889]|
|121994|       [16000, 7417]|
|144782|      [12139, 12139]|
|175886|        [7305, 7305]|
|221451|      [14889, 12139]|
|226945|             [18097]|
|250401|              [7278]|
|256892|        [7383, 5514]|
|270043|              [7442]|
|272338|              [7306]|
|284802|      [18310, 14898]|
+------+--------------------+
```

Referring to [Aggregating a One-Hot Encoded feature in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404744/aggregating-a-one-hot-encoded-feature-in-pyspark) and  [Encode and assemble multiple features in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982425/encode-and-assemble-multiple-features-in-pyspark/32984795#32984795) , I try to solve it with

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer

df_user_catlist = df_order.groupBy("userid").agg(F.collect_list('level3_cat').alias('categoryIndexes'))
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol='categoryIndexes', outputCol='categoryVec')
transformed_df = cv.fit(df_user_catlist).transform(df_user_catlist)
transformed_df.show()
```

But caught the following error

```
IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column category must be of type equal to one of the following types: [ArrayType(StringType,true), ArrayType(StringType,false)] but was actually of type ArrayType(IntegerType,true).'
```

I notice the difference is that the input data is of IntegerType instead of StringType, may I know (a) how can I convert it to StringType, or there's a better way to convert it to OHE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast string to category indexes:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_user_catlist = df_user_catlist \
    .withColumn('categoryIndexes', 
         F.col('categoryIndexes').cast('array<string>'))
```